# The probability of bomb hitting a bridge.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> The probability of bomb hitting a bridge is $\dfrac12$ and $2$ direct hits
>    are required to destroy it.What is the probability of the destruction
>   of bridge if only $5$ bombs are drops ?

$a.)\ 62.32\% \\
\color{green}{b.)\ 81.25\%} \\
c.)\ 45.23\% \\
d.)\ 31.32\% $

I did $4 \times \left(\dfrac12\right)^{5}=125\%$ but the answer given
is option $b.)\ $

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: Lets turn this problem into something more tangible. Lets thing of 5 consecutive bombs being dropped. If the bomb hits we will write H if it is a miss we will write M. How many different sequences are there? For example, if all five miss we have MMMMM. We know $Pr(M)=1/2$ and $Pr(H)=1/2$. Maybe you can go from there.

Comment: 125% makes no sense :) If the first drop is a success, then multiply by the probability of the other one given 4 attempts, if not consider the second, and so on (adding probabilities)...

Comment: $4\times \Big(\tfrac 1 2\Big)^5$ does not even *equal* $125\%$.  It's $12.5\%$ (which is still not the right answer to the question, but ...).

Answer (score 2):

The bridge is NOT destroyed, if no bomb or only one bomb hits the bridge.
The probability for $0$ hits is $\frac{1}{32}$, the probability for $1$
hit is $\frac{5}{32}$. The probability of desctruction is $1-\frac{1}{32}-\frac{5}{32}$